# javascript window.onresize on page load

Tags: javascript, window

I have a script which shows different content depending on the screen size, it looks like this:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
if ((window.innerWidth > 750 && window.innerWidth < 1250))  {

//Do something

}}
```

The above works absolutely fine when re-sizing the browser. My question is how can i get the above to work if the user opens the page up with a window width of say 750?

I have just tested this and obviously the event isn't triggered until the browser is re-sized, this is causing the above not to work

Comment: Why don't you use media queries instead?

Comment: I would recommend media queries as well. However, if you can use a library like JQuery, this would be as simple as $(document).ready(function(){ if (window.innerWidth == 750) { //Do Something }

Comment: @taylorc93 - i need to support older browsers that's why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var onResizing = function(event) {
if ((window.innerWidth > 750 && window.innerWidth < 1250))  {

//Do something

}};

window.onresize = onResizing;
window.onload = onResizing;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   if (window.innerWidth == 750) {
     // Do something
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The "onresize" function is an event listener that fires when the user resizes their page.  To get your code to run on page load you need to set it up to fire on the page load event instead (as the page load event is a different event from the resize event).

```
window.onload = function(event) {
    if ((window.innerWidth > 750 && window.innerWidth < 1250))  {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: this would then not do what i intend it to do and do something on resize

Comment: The fact that you downvoted this just proves that you don't understand  the accepted solution :/

Comment: i completely understand the answer, that's why i accepeted it. You missed out the element of resizing which was the main part of the question.

Comment: I was only trying to show you how to get it working onload - since you already knew how to set it up onresize.  Pretty lame reason to downvote an answer.